# string split dynamically in c#

Tags: c#, string

I need to get value which user put in a textbox

Input

> Transaction ID : 100000527054518  PNR No. : 6755980353    Train No. /
>   Name : 18615 / KRIYA YOGA EXP Date of Booking : 07-Jun-2016   Class :
>   SLEEPER CLASS   Quota : GENERAL Date of Journey : 13-Jun-2016     From :
>   HWH To : RNC Boarding At : HWH Date Of Boarding : 13-Jun-2016
>     Reservation Up to : RNC Distance : 416 KM Scheduled Departure : 22:10
>     Scheduled Arrival : 14-Jun-2016 ( 07:05 Hrs ) Total Fare : ? 500.0 &
>   SC : ? 23.0   Adult : 2 & Child : 0    Details of Passengers S.No.Name
>   Age Gender  Concession Status  Coach Seat / Berth / WL No    Current
>   Status  Coach Seat / Berth / WL No    ID Type / ID No. 1  AYAN
>   PAL   40  Male CNF S7  49 (LB) CNF S7  49 (LB)

```
string TransactionID="";
string pnrno="";
string trainno="";
string dateofbooking="";
string class="";
string Quota="";
```

OUTPUT

```
TransactionID=100000527054518 ;
pnrno=6755980353;
trainno=18615;
dateofbooking=13-Jun-2016;
class=SLEEPER CLASS;
Quota=GENERAL;
```

AND If Class Is AC 3 Tier

```
TransactionID=100000527054518 ;
    pnrno=6755980353;
    trainno=18615;
    dateofbooking=13-Jun-2016;
    class=AC 3 TIER;
    Quota=GENERAL;
```

Please help I am stuck with this from a time now

Comment: You should use some kind of text parsing API. `Split()` won't be much helpful here.

Comment: what should i use then

Comment: You should rethink your UI concept. Entering all the informations in *one* textbox will force input errors. Use a textbox for each part and the input is easier for the users and the postprocessing is easier for you

Comment: Where are you getting the data from?  Is it one line or multiple lines?  Do you have more than on input of this format in source?  Text files parsing must be kept in original format to successfully parse.  Been doing this for 40 years and can help.  Need exact format of input to help (and multiple samples if possible).

Comment: Transaction ID : 100000527054518 PNR No. : 6755980353 Train No. / Name : 18615 / KRIYA YOGA EXP Date of Booking : 07-Jun-2016 Class : SLEEPER CLASS Quota : GENERAL Date of Journey : 13-Jun-2016 From : HWH To : RNC Boarding At : HWH Date Of Boarding : 13-Jun-2016 Reservation Up to : RNC Distance : 416 KM Scheduled Departure : 22:10 Scheduled Arrival : 14-Jun-2016 ( 07:05 Hrs ) Total Fare : ? 500.0 & SC : ? 23.0 Adult : 2 
Age Gender Concession Status Coach Seat / Berth / WL No Current Status Coach Seat / Berth / WL No ID Type / ID No. 1 AYAN PAL 40 Male CNF S7 49 (LB) CNF S7 49 (LB)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Splitting of words Dynamically in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38026410/splitting-of-words-dynamically-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way is working but it's still text dependent one wrong ':' will crush your app,

```
string source = @"Transaction ID : 100000527054518 PNR No. : 6755980353 Train No. / Name : 18615 / KRIYA YOGA EXP Date of Booking : 07-Jun-2016 Class : SLEEPER CLASS Quota : GENERAL Date of Journey : 13-Jun-2016 From : HWH To : RNC Boarding At : HWH Date Of Boarding : 13-Jun-2016 Reservation Up to : RNC Distance : 416 KM Scheduled Departure : 22:10 Scheduled Arrival : 14-Jun-2016 ( 07:05 Hrs ) Total Fare : ? 500.0 & SC : ? 23.0 Adult : 2 & Child : 0 Details of Passengers S.No.Name
                        Age Gender Concession Status Coach Seat / Berth / WL No Current Status Coach Seat / Berth / WL No ID Type / ID No. 1 AYAN PAL 40 Male CNF S7 49(LB) CNF S7 49(LB)";

        string[] sourceArray = source.Split(':');

        string TransactionID = sourceArray[2].Split(' ')[0];
        string pnrno = "";
        string trainno = "";
        string dateofbooking = "";
        string classStr="";
        string Quota = "";
```

**Option 1**

If you have access to the source text you should write it like that:

> "Transaction ID : 100000527054518 | PNR No. : 6755980353 | ..."

after that you splitting the text by `split('|')` after that the next split will be by (':') so what you will get is `result[0] = type`, `result[1] = value`

after that in loop :

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < sourceArray.Count ; i++)
{
   string[] resultArr = sourceArray.Split(':');
   if(resultArr[0].Equals("Transaction ID")) TransactionId = resultArr[1];
   else if ...
}
```

If you can't edit the source you need to use indexes:

```
int transactionIndex = source.IndexOf("Transaction ID");
int pnrIndex = source.IndexOf("PNR No.");
```

and from index take the value from : to : substract the next type

for example the first will be 100000527054518 PNR No. - PNR No. = 100000527054518

**Option 2 and i think is the best**

use regular expresion

```
string transactionId;

string source = @"Transaction ID : 100000527054518 PNR No. : 6755980353 Train No. / Name : 18615 / KRIYA YOGA EXP Date of Booking : 07-Jun-2016 Class : SLEEPER CLASS Quota : GENERAL Date of Journey : 13-Jun-2016 From : HWH To : RNC Boarding At : HWH Date Of Boarding : 13-Jun-2016 Reservation Up to : RNC Distance : 416 KM Scheduled Departure : 22:10 Scheduled Arrival : 14-Jun-2016 ( 07:05 Hrs ) Total Fare : ? 500.0 & SC : ? 23.0 Adult : 2 & Child : 0 Details of Passengers S.No.Name
                        Age Gender Concession Status Coach Seat / Berth / WL No Current Status Coach Seat / Berth / WL No ID Type / ID No. 1 AYAN PAL 40 Male CNF S7 49(LB) CNF S7 49(LB)";

Regex transactionRegex = new Regex(@"Transaction ID : [0-9]+ PNR No.");
Match match = transactionRegex.Match(source);

if (match.Success)
{
   transactionId = match.Value.Replace("Transaction ID :", "").Replace("PNR No.", "");
}
```

Comment: but transaction Id PNR No.etc can be change for every user

Comment: @Ibibo the content not the headers

Comment: @Ibibo the transactionId can be any number [0-9]+

Comment: It was an answer not question 

Comment: The same logic you can do to the rest, better do it in a function that get the string as parameter and returning object that include all your values, if you need help just say.

Comment: i don't understand  can u explain

Comment: I will make it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You should use some kind of text parsing API. `Split()` won't be much helpful here. What you are trying to do is parse the given input and get you the tokens data. Some API's are like (but commercial and not free, though they have 30 days trial)

[Rosette Analytics](http://www.rosette.com/text-analytics-toolkit/?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=banner&utm_content=stack&utm_campaign=Rosette%20Text%20Analytics)

[Actonomy Parser](http://www.actonomy.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Ok so what i did is class that represent variables you asked to get from the string.

that class has one method that gets string and parsing it with regular expressions.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string source = @"Transaction ID : 100000527054518 PNR No. : 6755980353 Train No. / Name : 18615 / KRIYA YOGA EXP Date of Booking : 07-Jun-2016 Class : SLEEPER CLASS : GENERAL Date of Journey : 13-Jun-2016 From : HWH To : RNC Boarding At : HWH Date Of Boarding : 13-Jun-2016 Reservation Up to : RNC Distance : 416 KM Scheduled Departure : 22:10 Scheduled Arrival : 14-Jun-2016 ( 07:05 Hrs ) Total Fare : ? 500.0 & SC : ? 23.0 Adult : 2 & Child : 0 Details of Passengers S.No.Name
                            Age Gender Concession Status Coach Seat / Berth / WL No Current Status Coach Seat / Berth / WL No ID Type / ID No. 1 AYAN PAL 40 Male CNF S7 49(LB) CNF S7 49(LB)";

            MyClass mc1 = new MyClass();

            mc1.getObjectFromString(source);
        }

    }


    class MyClass
    {
        public string TransactionID { get; set; }
        public string pnrno { get; set; }
        public string trainno { get; set; }
        public string dateofbooking { get; set; }
        public string className { get; set; }
        public string Quota { get; set; }

        public void getObjectFromString(string source)
        {

            Regex transactionRegex = new Regex(@"Transaction ID : [0-9]+ PNR No.");
            Regex pnrnoRegex = new Regex(@"PNR No. : [0-9]+ Train No. / Name");
            Regex trainnoRegex = new Regex(@"Train No. / Name : [0-9]*[A-Za-z/ ]* Date of Booking");
            Regex dateofbookingRegex = new Regex(@"Date of Booking : [-0-9a-zA-Z/ ]* Class");
            Regex classNameRegex = new Regex(@"Class : [A-Za-z ]* CLASS");
            Regex QuotaRegex = new Regex(@"CLASS : [A-Za-z ]* Date of Journey");

            Match match = transactionRegex.Match(source);
            if (match.Success)
                this.TransactionID = match.Value.Replace("Transaction ID :", "").Replace("PNR No.", "");

            match = pnrnoRegex.Match(source);
            if (match.Success)
                this.pnrno = match.Value.Replace("PNR No. :", "").Replace("Train No. / Name", "");

            match = trainnoRegex.Match(source);
            if (match.Success)
                this.trainno = new String(match.Value.Replace("Train No. / Name :", "").Replace("Date of Booking", "").ToCharArray().Where(c => Char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray());

            match = dateofbookingRegex.Match(source);
            if (match.Success)
                this.dateofbooking = match.Value.Replace("Date of Booking :", "").Replace("Class", "");

            match = classNameRegex.Match(source);
            if (match.Success)
                this.className = match.Value.Replace("Class :", "").Replace("CLASS", "");

            match = QuotaRegex.Match(source);
            if (match.Success)
                this.Quota = match.Value.Replace("CLASS :", "").Replace("Date of Journey", "");

        }
    }
```

Comment: if it's working in your app you welcome to accept that answer.

Comment: I want it to store in a database but TransactionId And pnrno not apearing on button click


 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into testfbhv (TransactionId, pnrno) values('" + TransactionID + "','" + pnrno + "')", con);

Comment: trim the values and check if you get them in the mc1 object if yes you should check whats wrong with db

Comment: for better understanding what is regular expression visit : http://www.regular-expressions.info/